# Is there an option to change the width from the grid container in bootstrap theme?

Tags: impresspages

Is there a way to change the width from the grid container in bootstrap theme using IP or should i hack the CSS style sheet?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand why would you need this. Do you want to have GRID management narrower? Then add your own css file.

CSS can be added using ipAddCss function in ipBeforeController event.

You can add CSS only for particular admin pages. Use ipRoute()->... to get information about current page.